# Wordpress (custom theme) WON'T SCROLL on MAC browsers?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, osx-mountain-lion

I am creating a custom theme, made all the static html/css and now I am converting it to PHP for wp.

I don't know what I changed, but now whenever I make a change and reload, I cannot scroll down. There are no posts, this is not a blog, but the whole front page doesn't fit on the screen.

I turned on debugging and got a few errors I expected from plugins, but those plugins were active before when scroll was working. I am not using any javascript or jquery.

There is no scroll bar, and scrolling does not work (safari/chrome/firefox) but on my wife's PC in chrome it does work.

No ideas, please help!!

Comment: Did you try turning it off and back on again? Seriously though, you haven't provided anywhere near enough information for anyone to offer a sensible answer. Why don't you upload it somewhere and post the URL here?

Comment: Sorry [VPR](http://www.viewpoint-realty.com). That's the front page. I can provide the stylesheet if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

At the top of my stylesheet under html and body styles, I had

```
img { max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

That line works ok with a static site, just not the php generated wp site.